# How to keep idToken in server side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase-authentication

Yesterday I figured out how to give a user custom claims.
So now upon logging in I fetch the '/getMyClaims' post, and it gets what type of claims they have.

And when I log in as admin, I am able to go to the routes that are only admin, but sometimes randomly, the block is reverting back to false so it disallows even the admin. How do I keep the idToken recognized everytime? I have been having a hard time trying to find out how to make this work even when the documents provided and most resources are either for react or vue. I am using nodejs, and plain javascript and html.

My thoughts were to store the block, but I guess it is refreshing and then the variable block reverts to undefined.

Here is my server.js:

```
    var block;

var blockware = (req,res,next) => {
    if(block == true || block == undefined){
        return res.sendStatus(401);
    }
    next();
}

app.post('/getMyClaims', async(req,res) => {
    let {uid,idToken} = req.body;
    console.log(idToken.token)
    if(idToken.claims.type === 'customer'){
        block = true;
        console.log('deny')
    } else if(idToken.claims.type === 'admin'){
        block = false;
    } else {
        block = true;
    }
})

// admin only pages
app.get(['/seller','/add-product', '/add-product/:id'], blockware, (req,res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(staticPath, ''))
})
```

Comment: ID tokens don't revert after some time. In fact, they can't be modified after they're minted. So there must something going on that gives you either an older token, or that removes the custom claim from the token. But since the code you shared doesn't mint any tokens, it's impossible to say where this is happening based on the current information. I recommend logging each decoded token, and inspecting/sharing what you find in there.

Comment: That was a typo, I actually meant how to keep in the server while a user is logged in. I believe its coming my 'var block;' I did read that it gets a refresh after every request. So maybe block is not storing the false value as it should?

Comment: I also have the fetch('/getMyClaims') triggering once logged in.

Comment: ID tokens are pretty shortlived by design, the default for their expiry being is 60 minutes after they are minted. You should not depend on an ID token you receive for a request to be valid for much longer than it takes to handle that request (a few minutes is fine).

Comment: Ah i see. What would be the more efficient way of handling this then?

Comment: You should pass the ID token to your API with every call that requires it, and then not use it any longer than for the scope of that call (or a few minutes at most).

Comment: And what would be the option without ID tokens? Is there another way for me to grant a user permission to visit a route?

Comment: I said nothing about *not* passing the ID token, you just should not use the token beyond the lifecycle of the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generally never want to store idTokens or jwt's server side.  The purpose is for the client to send them along with each request like mentioned in one of the comments.

There is another problem with your code, is that it blindly trusts the token coming in.  Wherever that token is being created (your code doesn't show where this is), you need to validate that the token isn't expired, and hasn't been tampered with by communicating with the service or verifying yourself with your server-side secret.  Once it passes, only then you can trust the contents of the token and determine whether the user is a customer/admin/someone else.

See here for more info: https://medium.com/@mmoshikoo/simple-jwt-authentication-explanation-81e930a1a01f